# writing a plugin, how to disable the comment form altogether?

Tags: comments

I'm writing a protected-page plugin and want to disable comments on protected pages. I'm usually hooking into `the_content` but that's not enough for comments. I got into `comments_array` to block the existing comments, but how do I block `comments_template`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control whether comments appear by filtering the [`comments_open()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_open) function. Here is an example from the WordPress codex:

```
add_filter( 'comments_open', 'my_comments_open', 10, 2 );
function my_comments_open( $open, $post_id ) {

    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    if ( 'page' == $post->post_type )
        $open = false;

    return $open;
}
```